# Как увеличить область захвата при сдвиге бокового меню Android?

Tags: android, android-menu, android-navigation-drawer

android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Comment: Что такое область захвата?

Comment: А вообще прям интересно даже, что такое обл. захвата?)

Comment: Ну допустим я хочу открыть боковое меню не бургером, а движением пальца слева на право,однако область в которой я могу зацепить меню оч маленькая. Хочу ее расширить чтобы было удобнее сдвигать

Answer (score 3):

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
          android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
          android:layout_width="...dp" // Ваше желанное значение
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="start"
          app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
          app:menu="@menu/navigation_items"/>
```

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что область захвата и ширина это суть одно и тоже?..

Comment: Почему то с этим ассоциировалось, подсказка для меня "при сдвиге"  :D